# Find innermost rectangular bounding box of chip on pcb using OpenCV

Tags: c++, python-3.x, opencv3.0, contour

I'm working on segmenting the chip portion of `PCB` using `OpenCV`. I tried using the find contours method from the `opencv` library but I am not able to identify a way to find the innermost contour that has the chip.Can anyone help me?

Code for finding all contours -

```
img = cv2.imread(args['image'])
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0.5)
edge = cv2.Canny(blur, 0, 50, 3)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edge, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                       cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 2)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I want the innermost green colored bounded box from this image :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The flag `RETR_EXTERNAL` which you are using should be replaced by `RETR_TREE`. `RETR_EXTERNAL` flag when used gives out only the outermost contours. Thus, as the innermost bounding box, you wish to gain will not be detected as it is most probably always instead another contour. To eliminate this problem, use the `RETR_TREE` flag.

After that by using the `RETR_TREE` flag, you will get all the possible contours detected and their parent-child relationships will be stored in the variable `hierarchy`. Using this hierarchy, filter out the contours which have no child contours, thus, you will get the innermost contours.

[Refer this for info on RETR_* flags.](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_hierarchy/py_contours_hierarchy.html#contour-retrieval-mode)

[Refer this for info on hierarchy or parent-child relationship of contours.](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_hierarchy/py_contours_hierarchy.html#what-is-hierarchy)